# React don't rendering component inside angular-router or after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, reactjs

I am trying to a react example inside angular ui-router view. When I put the example code inside master of the page, namely when it load with document, it works fine.

However I put the code inside a view(which load via ajax async in SPA project) It didn't work. There is no action. How can I solve this problem. I think this is because of `babel`, It didn't look at contents which loaded async.

Here is the example of code.

```
<script type="text/babel">
    var Search = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
            return { showResults: false };
        },
    onClick: function() {
        this.setState({ showResults: true });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Search" onClick={this.onClick} />
                { this.state.showResults ? <Results /> : null }
            </div>);
        }
    });

    var Results = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
        return (
                <div id="results" className="search-results">
                    Some Results
                </div>
            );
        }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(<Search /> , document.getElementById('react-cont'));
</script>
```

Comment: lol why did you mix angular with react ?

Comment: Just need to show an example of React code inside angular project. No purpose to mixing them. Maybe I should use an Iframe

Comment: i hope you show it as a bad example, as a "don't do this!"

Comment: usually you don't ajax js you ajax the templates and the data , you load the js at page ready

Comment: Example is about a part of CSS product which claims that it can be used with angular, react and jquery. This not about React and angular.

Comment: i suggest you use plunker or something similar to display examples

Comment: Thank you, currently I solve with ```iframe```